# css file empty, how the styling works here in this project?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styling

I am a first grade CS student in university.After learning some of the basics of React.js. I am trying to understand a resume project. Can anyone tell me why the app.js and index.js are empty here. I wonder how the styling is accomplished...I spotted classname attributs inside jsx elements of the components but i can't find related css file in the src folder, could it be inside public folder then? Besides answering me questions, feel free to point out what kind of React topics/techniques I need to learn about in order to understand better how the styling works here.
The project repository by nordicgiant2: https://github.com/nordicgiant2/react-nice-resume

I have checked topic like how the styling working for component in React.js and the direct anwser haven't been found.

Comment: The image and link appears to have nothing to do with what you're asking..?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Styling may be due to bootstrap `scripts`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for your comments. I bielieve it's related, but I thinked i failed to explain my question clearly. The link is the project i tried to understand.Inside the linked repository you could find out, inside the src folder the app.js and index.js are empty. But the project's styling clearly works fine. Picture is used only to show that i do see those class name appeared inside component but same time classname related CSS file is not found.

Comment: @Reyno Hei, thanks for your advice. This is the first question I asked in stack overflow and as for the rules, I am not yet quite familiar with. I will definately pay more attention to those conventions next time. But this time as I mentioned at last commands to Rory McCrossan, picture is here only to points out that i did noticed inside the components there are classname attribute inside elements which makes me thinks there must be related CSS file somewhere.

Comment: @Ankit I think it could be the reason. I know nothing about bootstrap yet and I think I may need to learn about it now, I believe it would be related. Used to import one component into my former practice-project and I noticed the same thing where I couldn't understand how the imported component is styled.

Answer (score 0):

The styling turns to be inside the public folder, and when check the index.html file inside the public folder I realize the link tag points toward to the css file inside the public folder. My original assumption was that, the styling sheet should be place inside the src folder as the TUTORIAL said.
Below is a snippet of the inde.html of this project which reveal the answer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/media-queries.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/magnific-popup.css">
    <title>Nordic Giant Development</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script src="js/waypoints.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
    <script src="js/magnific-popup.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```